# Starting a URL from our ASP.NET intranet (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, intranet

I'm simply trying to call a URL from our Office Intranet, but depending on how I call it, it either acts like it did nothing (1st example), or throws an Access Denied error (2nd example).  However, if I run either of the following in Visual Studio 2013 (C#) they work great -- opens a new tab and goes to the site!  When I publish it to our intranet, however, it doesn't work.

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe", "https://google.com");
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Or,

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://google.com");
```

Referring to the 2nd example, I'm assuming it has something to do with running it locally in VS.  I read an article that said to try setting your service account to 'Local Service', which I did, but got the same error (access denied).  The same article then said to check the permissions on the application.  With an office intranet w/master pages, what permission on what files would I change -- if this is even the problem?  I gave the .aspx page that's got the URL call in it to have Full Control, which still gave the access denied error.

If I go to our server that's running IIS, open a browser, put the URL in, it goes to the site just fine -- meaning that server can get to the Internet.  Sorry I don't know a ton about setup on IIS or security on servers hosting intranets.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Where is your c# code running?  Is this a window application or a web application?  If it's a web application, why not just provide a link for the user to click, e.g. `<A HREF="https://google.com" Target="_blank"/>` ?

Comment: Could it be that local proxy is really denying your requests?

Comment: My c# code is running on our Intranet, which is always web-based, right?  Sorry, maybe I made my example a little too simple.  The button on the screen that they push after selecting an option, would really do something like:  https://google.com?param1=Dog   or  https://google.com?param1=Cat.  So pushing the button executes some c# code behind, where I construct my URL.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to call this URL from our Intranet without getting either Access Denied errors, or acting like pushing the button caused no action to take place.

Comment: As for a-man's comment, that could very well be the case, so my question for you would be, how would I determine if the local proxy is denying my request(s) and how would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the following, simple solution, to the above issue by searching the web getting ideas from links and anchor tags, etc.  Here's all I had to do to make this work on our Intranet:

```
Response.Redirect("https://google.com?param1=Dog");
```

Thanks for anyone trying to help!